# Pass Parameter from JSP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to get var in js from JSP.

I have this one :

```
<li class="cid<%=cat.getDisplayCategoryBO().getDispCtgrNo()%>">
    <a href="<%=url%>" onclick=""><%=cat.getDisplayCategoryBO().getDispCtgrNm()%>
    </a>
</li>
```

And I want to get the `<%=cat.getDisplayCategoryBO().getDispCtgrNo()%>` in js.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can give it an ID,

```
<li id="theList" class="cid<%=cat.getDisplayCategoryBO().getDispCtgrNo()%>"><a href="<%=url%>" onclick=""><%=cat.getDisplayCategoryBO().getDispCtgrNm()%></a></li>
```

Then you could get the class of the element, and then parse it.

```
$("#theList").attr("class").substring(3)
```